# React access <canvas/> ref of a child component

Tags: reactjs, canvas, save, ref, data-uri

I'm trying to save **canvas** as **PNG** file on the press of a button.

This is my code for now: **(this part is working)**

```
  const canvasRef01 = useRef(null);

  const saveAsPng = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef01.current;
    const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image / png");


    const aTag = document.createElement("a");
    aTag.href = dataURI;
    aTag.setAttribute("download", "Code Gallery by 0xLeoDev");
    document.body.appendChild(aTag);
    aTag.click();
    aTag.remove();
  };

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef01} />
    <button onClick={saveAsPng}>save as png</button>
  );
```

My **issue** start once i try to implement it with a child component.

```
<Parent/>   //I need to have my "saveAsPng" function  and <button/> here
<Child/>    //I've my <canvas/> tag inside this child
```

---

*The **question** is how to access (refer to) my canvas data from my parent component to get it's dataUrl?*

---

I've tried to solve it with hook defined as *dataURI* and *setDataURI*. With idea of passing it as a props. But this "solution" is looping my canvas.

```
  const [dataURI, setDataURI] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef01.current;

    const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image / png");
    // setDataURI(dataURI);

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const width = canvas.width;
    const height = canvas.height;
    draw(context, canvas, width, height, numOfRec, bacgroundColor);
  }, [draw]);

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef01}
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the ref and the `saveAsPng` method in the parent component instead, then pass the ref to the child component. In order for this to work, your child component must implement [`forwardRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef).

You will also need to pass the `saveAsPng` method down to that child.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const canvasRef01 = useRef(null);

  const saveAsPng = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef01.current;
    const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image / png");

    const aTag = document.createElement("a");
    aTag.href = dataURI;
    aTag.setAttribute("download", "Code Gallery by 0xLeoDev");
    document.body.appendChild(aTag);
    aTag.click();
    aTag.remove();
  };

  return (
    <Child ref={canvasRef01} onButtonClick={saveAsPng}/>
  );
}
```

```
const Child = React.forwardRef(({ onButtonClick }, ref) => {
  return (
    <>
        <canvas ref={ref} />
        <button onClick={onButtonClick}>save as png</button>
    </>
  );
})
```